Imapact of VBScript deprecation and removal on IIS classic server-side scripting
I have not found any documentation or info on what, if anything, the deprecation/removal of VBScript will do related to IIS. We have such a site with a lot of vb server-side scripting, e.g. to validate and send form-based emails, determine visitor browser agent, user language settings, etc.
Anyone have authoritative info on this, or at least can tell me why this is or isn't a valid worry - and not "re-write it all in JavaScript".
